# Rewrite so that denominator doesn't have any root expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to simplify the following equation:

$$ 4^{-1/3} + 6^{-1/3} + 9^{-1/3} $$

Also written as 1 over the cubed root of 4 plus the cubed root of 6 plus the cubed root of 9.

I'm so lost! I know how to simplify when there's one or two expressions in the denominator, but not three! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Did you know $4^{-1/3}=4^{2/3}/4$?

Comment: aha! That totally gets the denominator as a whole number! I thought I was supposed to be using some sort of sum of cubes formula... but that seems to work??

Comment: Thank you for writing back! They're in the numerator, so basically it would be what you wrote but with positive exponents in the denominator.  Sorry I don't have much experience with MathJax or I'd write it out!

Comment: Get a common denominator of $216^{1/3}$

Comment: So final answer is (18(2^1/3) + 6(36^1/3) + 4(81^1/3))/36)?

Answer (score 0):

$$ 4^{-1/3} + 6^{-1/3} + 9^{-1/3} =  
 4^{2/3}/4 + 6^{2/3}/6 + 9^{2/3}/9 =  
 (9×4^{2/3} + 6×6^{2/3} + 4×9^{2/3} )/36$$